# Add Checkbox value to salesforce

Tags: php

im new to salesforce integration.

i have a contact form in which i have a field called Optin/Optout filed which is checkbox. if the user tick that checkbox value should get captured in salesforce. but i could not do it. can anyone please help me in this.

here is my code what i have done so far.

index.php

```
<form action="salesforce.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="news" value="1" checked="checked"/>

</form>
```

salesforce.php

```
<?php
$newsletter = $_POST['news'];

if($newsletter == "1"){
$news_result = $newsletter;
}else{
$news_result = "0";
}


$req .= "&HasOptedOutOfEmail=" . urlencode($news_result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the method in the form, if no method is defined it will be a get method and you use post the get the value

if you do this it will work:

`<form action="salesforce.php" method="post">`

Comment: i want this value "$req .= "&HasOptedOutOfEmail=" . urlencode($news_result);"

to be captured in salesforce. can anyone pls help me

Comment: try this:


`<?php
$newsletter = (int) $_POST['news'];

if($newsletter == 1){
$news_result = $newsletter;
}else{
$news_result = 0;
}

$req .= "&HasOptedOutOfEmail=" . $news_result ;

?>`


Also set this in your code to check the post

`print_r($_POST);`

Comment: "&HasOptedOutOfEmail" is this the correct keyword or field name for checkbox in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emailOptOut" id="emailOptOut" value="1" />
```

this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using this it worked for me:

```
apex:inputCheckbox value="{!news.isSelected}"
     selected="{!news.isSelected}" immediate="true"
```